# matching a column with awk using regex

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have  a CSV file in which record number, element symbol and element name is written. I want to extract those lines in which second column (i.e element symbol) `does not contain the letters a,e,i,o,u,A,E,I,O,U.` So I wrote a script to achieve the same but it is giving me all the lines.

This is my script:

```
awk -F',' '$2~/[^aeiouAEIOU]/' sample.txt
```

The sample.txt file:

```
102,No,Nobelium
103,Lr,Lawrencium
104,Rf,Rutherfordium
105,Db,Dubnium
106,Sg,Seaborgium
107,Bh,Bohrium
108,Hs,Hassium
109,Mt,Meitnerium
110,Ds,Darmstadtium
111,Rg,Roentgenium
112,Cn,Copernicium
113,Nh,Nihonium
114,Fl,Flerovium
115,Mc,Moscovium
116,Lv,Livermorium
117,Ts,Tennessine
118,Og,Oganesson
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$ awk -F',' '$2!~/[aeiouAEIOU]/' sample.txt
103,Lr,Lawrencium
104,Rf,Rutherfordium
105,Db,Dubnium
106,Sg,Seaborgium
107,Bh,Bohrium
108,Hs,Hassium
109,Mt,Meitnerium
110,Ds,Darmstadtium
111,Rg,Roentgenium
112,Cn,Copernicium
113,Nh,Nihonium
114,Fl,Flerovium
115,Mc,Moscovium
116,Lv,Livermorium
117,Ts,Tennessine
```

- `!~` to return false on a match
- `$2~/[^aeiouAEIOU]/` means return true if second field contains any non-vowel character.. so, `No` will match because `N` is non-vowel character

  - this can be corrected by whole string match: `$2~/^[^aeiouAEIOU]+$/`
- `tolower($2) !~ /[aeiou]/` can also be used instead of `$2 !~ /[aeiouAEIOU]/`

Comment: It is working. But my question is, why we cannot use [^] inside the character class to negate it ?